# Proving that an improved chinese remainder theorem algorithm returns $y^{d} \mod n$ *heavy modular math*

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Suppose you're given the algorithm:

$CRT(n,d_p,d_q,M_p,M_q,y)$

$x_p = y^{d_p} \mod p$

$x_q = y^{d_q} \mod q$

$x = M_pqx_p+M_qpx_q \mod n$

return $x$

If $d_K(y) = y^d \mod n$, $n = pq$, $d_p = d \mod (p-1)$, $d_q = d \mod (q-1)$, $M_p = q^{-1} \mod p$, and $M_q = p^{-1} \mod q$, how can we show that the returned $x$ is in fact $y^d \mod n$?

It would be very helpful if someone could clear up the notation for me, as I believe that is the part that is making me most confused. In actuality, we must show that $M_pqx_p+M_qpx_q \mod n$ = $((q^{-1} \mod p)(q)(y^{d_p} \mod p) + (p^{-1} \mod q)(p)(y^{d_q} \mod q)) \mod n$ = $y^d \mod n$, but it is not so clear to me how to proceed to prove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $y^{d_p} \equiv y^d\pmod p$ and $y^{d_q} \equiv y^d\pmod q$, by Fermat's little theorem. (I assume you mean that $p$ and $q$ are primes.) So you have $x_p \equiv y^d\pmod p$ and $x_q \equiv y^d\pmod p$. The final formula is then the standard way to find the residue class modulo $pq$ that satisfies those two congruences. And any number satisfying both congruences must be congruent to $y^d$ modulo $pq$, since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Can you please explain "the standard way to find the residue class modulo $pq$"? Are there any references that will help me come to $x$ from these two?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#A_constructive_algorithm_to_find_the_solution